# how to create an instance of selenium webdriver without building the browser in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I want to create an instance of webdriver(selenium) without building the browser. That is,

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();
```

i dont want to build the browser because, I want to keep the driver in a common place, if i use build a new chrome browser launches. And the application opens up new browser everytime I call it.

Is it possible to do that?. Let me know if any further information is required.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is the expected behaviour, each time you create an instance of WebDriver (Firefox, Chrome etc), it will launch the new browser. From my knowledge, you CAN NOT use the already opened browser, which is launched manually.

Why you call the webdriver instance each time? that will launch the new browser each time.

If you want to use `existing driver instance` (not the browser which is launched manually, but the browser launched by the driver instance), then define the driver variable as `global`, so it is available across the tests.